# How can I show an hidden view if a Recycler View is overscrolled vertically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overscroll

I would like to show an hidden search bar when my recycler view is over scrolled vertically. This would replicate the way that the search bar pops up in Whatsapp and on Spotify.

I think that a way to do this would be to detect the over scroll on the recycler view and then show the bar. But I don't know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use some already developed library from GitHub instead of doing it by your own. Some of the links are following

1. https://medium.com/@dan1ve/android-howto-material-design-tabs-scrolling-like-in-google-play-music-12273ce07bc
2. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout
3. https://androiddvlpr.com/android-animation-library/